# Insert Excel file data into database table using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, file

I am developing on web application that will get the excel file using FileUpload control in asp.net c#. Now when click on submit button, i want to insert the excel data into my database table. I have database in SQL-Server. The field of database table & excel file are same.I want to insert that excel's data into my database table. So how can i do this?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: To get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx Then once you provide more information (what you've tried), I'm sure SO will.

Comment: refer http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/09/import-data-from-excel-to-sql-database.html

Comment: I am refering "http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/09/import-data-from-excel-to-sql-database.html" this code, but i am getting this lrge error " D:\Users\Other\Test.xlsx File Extension : .xlsxException : The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator. ". so please suggest me what to do?

Comment: Hi, i got the solution , but there is one problem still, the problem is that, i have cone column in excel file that will contain time value, and the same field i have in my database with time(7) as a datatype. so now when i import the data then it will give error like this " The given value of type DateTime from the data source cannot be converted to type time of the specified target column. ". So can i import time related data in this case ?

Comment: @Deepak.Aggrawal Please do not submit edits that merely apply **bold** formatting to words like this.

Answer (score 3):

Others have mentioned using Excel interop to read the Excel file in the comments, but this is NOT safe to do for a web application that may have multiple users.

To get started, have a look at the [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) project.  I've used this several times for processing Excel files from a web application and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OLEDB classes to read directly from Excel file using the Excel drivers in OleDbConnection. Get the data in a datatable and save it to database.

```
 string connectString =
                "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=d:\\testit.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            // Save your datatable records to DB as you prefer.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing NPOI as a replacement for another 3rd party Excel parsing library.

https://code.google.com/p/npoi/

So far it seems to work pretty well and have a very complete feature set.  Of course, if all you need is very basic Excel data reading (and no writing), then the other DB connection style interfaces mentioned here should work well enough.

**EDIT: added sample code**

```
using( FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) )
{
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    double value = wb.GetSheet("Sheet1").GetRow(1).GetCell(1).NumericCellValue;
    // read other values as necessary.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try the following code . maybe its crude but it works

```
string connectString =
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\\data\\exceltest.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;user id=sa;pwd=windows;database=exceltest");
        sqlc.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from table1", sqlc);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table1", sqlc);
        sda.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into table1", sqlc);
        DataTable dbset = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dbset);
        SqlCommand cmdinsert = new SqlCommand();
        cmdinsert.Connection = sqlc;
        foreach (DataRow dsrc in dt.Rows)
        {
            string insertcommand = "insert into table1" + dbset.TableName + " ";
            string cols = "";
            string vals = "";
            DataRow dr = dbset.NewRow();
            foreach (DataColumn clm in dt.Columns)
            {
                dr[clm.ColumnName] = dsrc[clm.ColumnName].ToString(); ;
                if (cols.Length > 0)
                {
                    cols += ",[" + clm.ColumnName+"]";
                }
                else
                {
                    cols = "["+clm.ColumnName+"]";
                }
                if (vals.Length > 0)
                {
                    vals += "," + "'" + dsrc[clm.ColumnName].ToString() + "'";
                }
                else
                {
                    vals = "'" + dsrc[clm.ColumnName].ToString() + "'";
                }

            }
            insertcommand += "(" + cols + ") values("+vals+")";
            cmdinsert.CommandText = insertcommand;
            cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            insertcommand = "";

        }

        sqlc.Close();
```